# handling a full calendar event object

Tags: jquery, events, object, fullcalendar

Wanted to know how I create an object and fill him with info so I can add him to the full calendar jquery plugin.
So far I did something like :

```
            var eventsArray = [];
            var newEvent = new Object();

            newEvent[title] = "some text";
            newEvent[start] = d1;        //got date string here exactly similar to the calendar's
            eventsArray.push(newEvent);

             var formattedEventData = [] ;
            for (var k = 0; k < eventsArray.length; k ++) {
                formattedEventData.push({

                    title: eventsArray[k][0],
                    start: eventsArray[k][1]
                });
            }

             $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                  eventsource: formattedEventData,
                  events: formattedEventData,
                    color: 'yellow',
                    textColor: 'black'
            });
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource',formattedEventData);
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

I forgot to say... Everything happens okay without crashes... But nothing new in calendar.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I corrected your code from above. Take a look at this:

```
var eventsArray = [];
var newEvent = [];

newEvent[0] = "some text";
newEvent[1] = new Date(y, m, d); //got date string here exactly similar to the calendar's
eventsArray.push(newEvent);

var formattedEventData = [];
for (var k = 0; k < eventsArray.length; k++) {
    formattedEventData.push({
        title: eventsArray[k][0],
        start: eventsArray[k][1]
    });
}

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //eventsource: formattedEventData,
    events: formattedEventData,
    color: 'yellow',
    textColor: 'black'
});
//$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', formattedEventData);
//$('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

Few points to note here:

1. If you want the newEvent to be an object, use this to create it: var newEvent = {title:"some text", start:new Date(y, m, d)};
2. You can't initialize an array as newEvent[title]. Arrays are integer index based.
3. `eventSources` and `events` can't be used together. If you have multiple event sources, then you need to include the `events` array *inside* your `eventSources`:

   eventSources: [
         {
           events: [
             {
               ...
             }
           ]
         }
       ]

Answer (score 1):

See this:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/

You can use it like this:

```
var newEvent = new Object();

newEvent.title = "some text";
newEvent.start = new Date();
newEvent.allDay = false;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent );
```

Please note that when you assign value to [start](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) it needs to be in one of the supported formats.

You may specify a string in IETF format (ex: "Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST"), a string in ISO8601 format (ex: "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z") or a UNIX timestamp.

Hope this helps. Thanks